# Setting up OpenCV with Windows 7 and Code Blocks

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, mingw, codeblocks

I have successfully built OpenCV and I have come to the point where code::blocks recognizes the OpenCV syntax and successfully builds the program. However when I run I get this error

"The procedure entry point_gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll."

I am using Code::Blocks v 12.11 and minGW (the most recent, I can't remember the version number) along with OpenCV-2.4.8 Has anyone ever seen this problem? Help if you can, anything right now might work since I am so close.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895879/installing-opencv-on-windowsw32-to-be-used-with-code-blocks?rq=1

Using this link to the other question I was able to locate a hint for my problem. I had everything correct and the hint to change the build to a GUI Application solved the issue. The programs build and then run as they should.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818546/codeblocks-opencv-compiles-fine-but-gives-a-console-window-each-time?rq=1 
Correction, this is the actual link to the hint I needed to solve me issue